# Doesn't add records into PouchDB when used same function over again

Tags: javascript, couchdb, pouchdb

I'm trying to create a database with "users" and their data in it. Strangely it doesn't `put()` new variables in it when I try to for the third time. To do all this I create a local database `dblocal` and replicate this DB to the remote db called `dbremote`. At first I create a document with one variable.

```
function newuser() {
    if (window.document.consent_form.consent_to_share.value) {
        var id = "p" + Date.now() + "-" + Math.floor(Math.random() * 10000);
        var dblocal = new PouchDB(id);
        var consenttoshare = window.document.consent_form.consent_to_share.value;
        document.cookie = id;
        var dbremote = 'http://localhost:5984/experiment';
        dblocal.put({
            _id: id,
            consent: consenttoshare
        });
        dblocal.replicate.to(dbremote, {live: true});
    }
}
```

This all worked well, in another js file I'm trying to add a variable to the same document by executing the following function `putdb()`. Im doing this in the following way (as said in their documentation is the right way):

```
function putdb () {
    if (document.cookie){
        var id = document.cookie;
        var loggedin = "True";

        var dblocal = new PouchDB(id);
        dblocal.get(id).then(function (doc) {
            doc.loggedin = loggedin;
            return dblocal.put(doc);
        }).then(function () {
            return dblocal.get(id);
        }).then(function (doc) {
            console.log(doc);
            var dbremote = 'http://localhost:5984/experiment';
            dblocal.replicate.to(dbremote, {live: true});
        });
    }
}
```

This succesfully added the variable `loggedin` to the document as I wanted. However upon trying to add information to this document for the third time (again in another js file), nothing happens. I used exactly the same approach as before but only use different variables.

```
function putdb (checked) {
    if (document.cookie) {
        var id = document.cookie;
        var checkedlist = [];    
        for (i = 0; i < checked; i++) {
            checkedlist.push($("input[type=checkbox]:checked")[i].value)
        }
        var playlistname = document.getElementById("playlistname").value;

        var dblocal = new PouchDB(id);
        dblocal.get(id).then(function (doc) {
            doc.checkedlist = checkedlist;
            doc.playlistname = playlistname;
            return dblocal.put(doc);
        }).then(function () {
            return dblocal.get(id);
        }).then(function (doc) {
            console.log(doc);
            var dbremote = 'http://localhost:5984/experiment';
            dblocal.replicate.to(dbremote, {live: true});
        });
    }
}
```

I checked all variables, they are correct. 
I tried plain text variables. 
The script does run. 
I tried to add information to the document the way I did the first time. 
None of all this seems to add another variable to the document as I wanted in the last function. I think it has to do with the way pouchDB works which I don't know. help is much appreciated!

Comment: Creating and forgetting local db's like this over time may create a *huge* mess of abandoned IndexedDB pouch instances (wasted user space).  Use a single db with a consistent name for all users.  Also your _id's are risky so be prepared to handle 409's.  Since your _id's are not conveying information, consider using [uuidjs/uuid](https://github.com/) or the like.

Comment: As it turned out, the problem was due to asynchronous code. the function didn't fully retrieved the promise but already moved on to the next page.

Answer (score 2):

There are a number of problems in your code that results in bad usage of PouchDB, and may lead to problems.

First of all, it does not make a lot of sense to give your document the same id as the name of your database. Assuming you want a one database per user approach, there are two approaches you can follow.

**Multiple document approach**
You can instead make multiple documents within the same database with different id's. For instance, your 'consent' information may be stored like this:

```
var id = "p" + Date.now() + "-" + Math.floor(Math.random() * 10000);
let dblocal = new PouchDB(id);
document.cookie = id;
let dbremote = 'http://localhost:5984/experiment';
dblocal.put({
    _id: "consent",
    consent: window.document.consent_form.consent_to_share.value
});
dblocal.replicate.to(dbremote, {live: true});
```

While your playlist information is stored like this:

```
dblocal.put({
    _id: "playlist",
    name: playlistname,
    itemsChecked: checkedlist
});
```

**Single-document approach**
The second option is to store a single document containing all the information you want to store that is associated to a user. In this approach you will want to fetch the existing document and update it when there is new information. Assuming you named your document `global-state` (i.e. replace "consent" in the first code snippet with "global-state"), the following code will update a document:

```
dblocal.get("global-state").then((doc)=>{
    doc.loggedIn = true; // or change any other information you want
    return dblocal.put(doc);
}).then((response)=>{
    //handle response
}).catch((err)=>{
    console.log(err);
});
```

Furthermore, you should only call the

```
dblocal.replicate.to(dbremote, {live: true});
```

function once because the 'live' option specifies that future changes will automatically be replicated to the remote database.

Comment: Is there a preferred way to save the users to the db? either every user gets a database itself or every user is a document in the database.

Comment: @KenGeelhoed It depends on your project specification. If inserted data changes over the course of your application it may be more suitable to use a global state and update this. If your data is mostly static (e.g. log files) it is much easier to just create new documents.